# Why am I getting Property X not in projection in google appengine NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So I have the following Python model:

```
class PortalLocation(Model):
    location_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    location_code_new = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True) 
    location_code_old = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    location_wd_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
    location_sn_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
    location_street = ndb.StringProperty()
    location_borough = ndb.StringProperty()    
    location_state = ndb.StringProperty()    
    location_zip = ndb.StringProperty()    
    location_network_name = ndb.StringProperty() 
    location_network_manager = ndb.StringProperty()
    location_longitude = ndb.FloatProperty()
    location_latitude = ndb.FloatProperty()
    location_institution = ndb.StringProperty()
    updated_dt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

If I try to perform a projection query like this:

```
@classmethod
def get_all_locations_short(cls):
    query =  cls.query()
    location_list = query.fetch(200, projection=[cls.location_name])
    return location_list
```

I get an error that looks like this:

```
Property location_state is not in the projection
```

This example is structured almost the same as is in Googles documentation so I'm a little lost as to why this isn't working.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Is that the only query you have?  Projections require an index for the projected properties and whilst I see that `location_name` *is* indexed, `location_state`, isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason is you do not have an index for that property.

See the docs for limitations.

> Projection queries are subject to the following limitations:
>
> Only indexed properties can be projected.
>
> Projection is not supported for unindexed properties, including long
>   text strings (Text), and long byte strings (Blob).
>
> The same property cannot be projected more than once.

Comment: Yep as soon as I added the index to the app.yaml file it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `location_state` but you're telling your query to only return `location_name` for each entity. `location_state` needs to be part of the list you pass as `projection` to `fetch`. If you're not using location_name, then you can remove that and save an index.

```
location_list = query.fetch(200, projection=[cls.location_state])
```